# Enable SCHANNEL Protocols in Windows Registry (Win7 & 2012R2) DisabledByDefault or Enabled?

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication, cryptography, openssl

I have enabled TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2 protocols on my local Win7 machine and 2012R2 server as well as disabled SSL 2.0/3.0 using the registry DWord value DisabledByDefault = 0 based on the following Microsoft support article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030
(see SCHANNEL\Protocols subkey...)

But i noticed another TechNet article which seems to contradict this KB article by saying you should use set the Enabled DWORD value = 0xffffffff for each Protocols subkeys (Client or Server).
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418.aspx

Which value should be used to properly enable the protocols and/or any of the other SCHANNEL settings like CipherSuites and Key Exchanges?  Does one have more precedence over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable, use a value of 0, like this:
[image]

To enable, use a value of, 0xffffffff like this:
[image]

You can confirm which ciphers/protcols are enabled by using [SSL Scan](https://code.google.com/p/sslscan-win/downloads/detail?name=SSLScan-1.8.2-win-r7.zip&can=2&q=).
[image]